# Rails generate database rows on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database in my Rails app that holds a list of `positions` in each `project`.  The user can add/delete positions for the current project they are working on.  There are a few of these positions I would like to come as defaults when a user creates a new project.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'd suggest using an after_save callback in your project model

So, in your model:

```
def before_save
  @was_a_new_record = new_record?
  return true
end    
after_save :create_positions

def create_positions
  Position.create name: 'Manager', project_id: self.id if @was_a_new_record
  # repeat as required
end
```

Comment: OK, I seem to get in trouble for making too many assumptions,  as I fill in some gaps with likely values, and assume that these will be adjusted to match how models are actually set up.  My bad, I'll go more carefully. I have assumed your Position class name and the variables you've assigned in it. Do they match, do you have a particular error?

Comment: I have a position title string called `positions` and each position has a `project_id` which should be the new project created.  I have adjusted the code you provided to fit these values and I don't get an error however nothing seems to show up on the table I have that should show the positions associated with the current project.  EDIT: i just debugged a bit and see there is no project_id being saved on the create.

Comment: Ah, stupid me, I'd is not set yet. I'll do a quick amend

Answer (score 1):

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :positions

   before_create :set_positions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions #-> required for Rails 4.2+

   private

   def set_positions
      3.times do
         self.positions.build
      end
   end
end
```

---

> when a user creates a new project

The above will build the associated `position` objects before you create a `project`. You can add specific attributes to each of the new objects:

```
self.projects.build name: "test"
```

The beauty of it is that all the records will be saved at the same time, making it especially efficient.

Comment: Each position has an associated project_id, would that be able to be created through this method as well? If you look at the answer above yours that would show this dilemma.